# How to check if a Gtk Constant (GdkWindowState) contains a flag

Tags: python, gtk3

It makes a while that I've been searching to find how to check if a Gtk Constant of type `GdkWindowState` contains a flag.

I'm currently doing this:

```
    state=self.window_root.get_window().get_state()

    if 'GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN' in str(state):
         ...
```

Where `self.window_root` is a `Gtk.Window`

This is a soft hack, but I'd like to do it in the proper way by using `Gdk.WindowState.FULLSCREEN`

I've tried some things like: `if Gdk.WindowState.FULLSCREEN in state:`  but the constant is not iterable. And I'd like to point that just using `if Gdk.WindowState.FULLSCREEN == state:` doesn't works because the window is also focused.

When I print `state` I get:

`<flags GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN | GDK_WINDOW_STATE_FOCUSED of type 
GdkWindowState>`

So I actually see that there is an `|` operator and I think that it should be possible to do something with it. Something like `state.get_flags()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PyGtk documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gdk-constants.html#gdk-window-state-constants), GdkWindowState is a set of bit flags. Try converting it to integer value and use binary AND:

```
if Gdk.WindowState.FULLSCREEN & int(state):
    # ...
```

Actually it's quite possible the GdkWindowState class supports this operation directly, or has some standard methods to convert to integer.

You can use `print dir(state)` to see what fields and methods are available, and investigate from there.

Comment: The class supports it directly, there's no need of converting to int. Thanks for the answer!